# TypeScript export an imported object

Tags: typescript

Why can I not do this in TS?

```
import * as Module from './someplace'
export {
  Module.Thing as Thing
}
```

And is there some way I can? It doesn't seem like you are allowed to export with dot notation, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Not really. Still not sure what to do

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that the `export { A as B } from './c'` syntax requires named exports. Those named exports can either be a an explicit name from your program, or `default`.  `Module.Thing` is not a named export of the imported file, is a property of the object `Module`.

The syntax you propose isn't bad, really, but that's not syntax that's been implemented by the typescript compiler.

The `import *` here doesn't matter. Even though `Thing` was exported by `./someplace`, after that import, it's a single object.

But there's a few options depending on what makes the most sense for the rest of your codebase.

You could re-export only the named export you want from the file that exports it. But then you don't get the `import *` for use in that file.

```
export { Thing } from './someplace
```

Or you can always just export a `const` that's been assigned whatever you want. This is probably closest to your original intent.

```
import * as Module from './someplace'
export const Thing = Module.Thing
```